# Understanding NSLog syntax

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog

(I'm a cocoa beginner and ) I'm wondering why we should do:

```
NSLog(@"this is the variable value: %d",variable);
```

and not something like this:

```
[NSLog outputThis:@"this is the variable value: %d" param:variable];
```

Comment: Because second statement calls `outputThis:param:` method on `NSLog` object. `NSLog` is just a function in Cocoa framework.

Comment: yes but it could have been a class method for a class NSLog, like [NSString stringWithString:@"this is a string"]; ?

Comment: NSLog does not "sound" like class. NSLogger would've been better choice for a class name. Now it's just an action.

Comment: because the second one looks shit and we should feel blessed for anything that looks more like C ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I agree this is pretty confusing when you're starting out.  The main reason is that the NSLog method, like many others in Core Foundation, is a C-based API, rather than an Objective-C API.  C-style functions look like this *myFunction(myParameter1, myParameter2)*.

All the GUI stuff you're probably used to [UIView presentModalViewController:] etc is based around an Objective-C API, with the square brackets that you've seen for functions (called selectors in Obj-C) .  The Objective-C language sits on top of C, so you will find both styles in most apps.

Comment: Apple decides everything, and we 'll like it

Comment: ^ is the story of every iOS developer XD

Answer (score 7):

`NSLog` may *seem* like a class, but it isn't.

> `NSLog` is a `FoundationKit` function for printing debug statements to the
>   console. It is defined in `NSObjCRuntime.h`:

```
void NSLog(NSString format, ...);
```

There is a good amount of information here: <s>http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog</s>

**EDIT:** As @fyngyrz pointed out, the page is dead. So [here is a wayback-machine version of the page from 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20121214131714/http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog)

Comment: No, there isn't. The page is gone.

Comment: @fyngyrz Thanx. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, NSLog isn't an Objective C function but a C function built into the foundation of Cocoa. Therefore it conforms to basic C functions with variadic arguments.